# How to copy a file with spaces in its file name from one bucket to the other using AWS CLI (Dos)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am trying to copy a file by the same `My CV 2017.pdf` from one AWS bucket to the other using the AWS command line. But I am getting error doing that.

I tried using `My\ Cv\ 2017.pdf` and `'My CV 2017.pdf'`, both did not work.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use double quotes. For example:

`aws s3 cp "s3://source-bucket/My CV 2017.pdf" "s3://destination-bucket/My CV 2017.pdf"`

Comment: You can also use single quotes instead of double quotes. If you have bad number of arguments, you can use `aws s3 cp --debug <remaining arguments>` to debug and see how the arguments break down.

Answer (score 2):

Using double quotes can solve the problem when you have single file to upload.

For the bulk files, try uploading directory with recursive option

`aws s3 mv ../directory-with-files/ s3://bucket-name/folder-to-upload/ --recursive`

Comment: that indeed solved the invalid argument error for me

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved by adding
signature_v2 = True
to the s3cfg file.

Comment: This is a temporary fix since signature_v2 is deprecated.