# How to downloading a folder with space(s) in its name from Amazon S3 to local machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We are trying to download a folder with spaces to our local machine using AWS CLI.

Let's assume we have a folder with title **My Folder Name**, and we would like to download this folder along with files on our local machine.

We tried multiple options and still we are unable to download the folder.

```
aws s3 cp s3://MyBucket/My Folder Name c:\awstest --recursive
```

What's the right way to escape the space characters?

Comment: The question was also answered here: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46997354/how-to-copy-a-file-with-spaces-in-its-file-name-from-one-bucket-to-the-other-usi)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy a file with spaces in its file name from one bucket to the other using AWS CLI (Dos)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46997354/how-to-copy-a-file-with-spaces-in-its-file-name-from-one-bucket-to-the-other-usi)

Comment: The solution provided in the above link doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You can either escape the spaces individually with `\` (there's a space after the backslash):

```
$ aws s3 cp s3://MyBucket/My\ Folder\ Name c:\awstest --recursive
```

or the whole path with `'`s:

```
$ aws s3 cp 's3://MyBucket/My Folder Name' c:\awstest --recursive
```

Comment: Above options didn't work for me. I get "Unknown options: c:\awstest" when I execute the command.