# Copying with Lambda not working on files with spaces

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I've been working on Lambda functions and s3 buckets recently, and am coming up with an issue with copying. I made a function that when you upload a file to a certain bucket, it copies it to another bucket while putting it into a folder based on the extension. It then deletes the original file. You can see the code below:

```py
import json
import boto3
import os
    
# boto3 S3 initialization
s3_client = boto3.client("s3")
   
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    destination_bucket_name = 'destination_storage'
    
    # event contains all information about uploaded object
    print("Event :", event)
    
    # Bucket Name where file was uploaded
    source_bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
       
    # Filename of object (with path)
    file_key_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
       
    # Parse file type
    file_name, file_extension = os.path.splitext(file_key_name)
       
    # Come up with file path
    folder_name = file_extension.replace('.', '')
       
    # New Filename with new Path
    new_file_key_name = folder_name + "/" + file_key_name
    
    # Copy Source Object
    copy_source_object = {'Bucket': source_bucket_name, 'Key': file_key_name}
    
    # S3 copy object operation
    s3_client.copy_object(CopySource=copy_source_object, Bucket=destination_bucket_name, Key=new_file_key_name)
       
    # Delete file in paste bucket
    s3_client.delete_object(Bucket=source_bucket_name, Key=file_key_name)
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from S3 events Lambda!')
    }
```

However, I have noticed a problem. When uploading a file with a space in the name, the file stays in the source bucket and isn't copied over at all. I thought the source was splittext(), but my research iseems to show it working properly. Is there an issue with spaces with s3 that I missed? Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: you need to use double quotes for the file name that has spaces so that spaces are escaped, an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/46997703/13126651

Comment: Where exactly would I need to add them? For just new_file_key_name or the original as well?

Comment: its not able to find the original one so go for original and if you want that your destination file name should not have spaces then add for new file too

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for the Amazon S3 [event message structure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/notification-content-structure.html) contains this comment:

> The s3 key provides information about the bucket and object involved in the event. The object key name value is URL encoded. For example, "red flower.jpg" becomes "red+flower.jpg" (Amazon S3 returns "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" as the content type in the response).

This means that spaces, along with some other characters, will not be delivered as is, so you're not able to find the filename given the encoded string, and your copy is failing.  You'll need to decode the S3 path using something like this:

```python
    from urllib.parse import unquote_plus
    # Filename of object (with path)
    file_key_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    # Decode the URL encoded key name
    file_key_name = unquote_plus(file_key_name)
```

Comment: I appear to still be having issues. Does the copy_source_object need to have an encoded key in order to work? And does the new_file_key_name have to be encoded in order to copy?

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this too, this worked for me.

```
import boto3
from urllib.parse import unquote_plus

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    try:
        source_bucket = ""
        destination_bucket = ""
    
        s3 = boto3.client("s3")
    
        bucket_name = event["Records"][0]["s3"]["bucket"]["name"]
        object_key = event["Records"][0]["s3"]["object"]["key"]
  
        file_key_name = unquote_plus(object_key)
    
        copy_source = {"Bucket": bucket_name, "Key": file_key_name}
        s3.copy_object(Bucket=destination_bucket, CopySource=copy_source, Key=file_key_name)
        s3.delete_object(Bucket=source_bucket, Key=file_key_name)  # Use the decoded key here
    
        return {
            "statusCode": 200,
            "body": "ok"
        }

     except Exception as e:
        return {
            "statusCode": 500,
            "body": f"error occurred: {str(e)}"
        }
```